# Volumetrics behind transparent objects in eevee

Tags: transparency, volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene where I want to put an object with a volume renderer under glass, but I've discovered that my volumes don't seem to render when they're behind a transparent object.

[image]

I'm new to eevee, and relatively new to blender overall, so I don't know if this is an inherent limitation of the renderer or if there's a setting I need to change, or functionality I need to turn on.

Can I fix this?

Comment: could you provide your .blend? Or maybe a screenshot of your shadertree/material settings. For me it's working fiine, with glass, refraction and transparency shader. Alpha set to Multiply

Comment: I could post those, but your suspicion was right - I didn't change the Alpha blend mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris pointed me in the right direction - I had the blend mode set to opaque.  Changing it to multiply fixed my render.